# Can you use JSON.stringify on an array with objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing, local-storage

I have this code:

```
let myArray= [{
    gained: 0,
    lost: 0
}];

localStorage.setItem('allPoints', JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

This works fine but if I want to parse it

```
localStorage.getItem('allPoints', JSON.parse(allPoints));
```

I get following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON

Can't you parse an array like this?
Is there a way around this?

Comment: From where did you get the idea that `Storage.getItem()` takes a second parameter? There's no mention of this [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem)

Comment: I guess I accidentally did this and I didnt see it ‍♂️

Comment: correct JS should be : `let myArrLs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('allPoints') || '[]' )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely can.

You only got it a bit wrong with getItem.

It should be:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allPoints"))
```

You first need to retrieve the value. You might want to check also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem.

And then you apply JSON.parse